# ISAPI rewrite - ignore subdirectory

Tags: iis, isapi-rewrite

I have a site where I am using an ISAPI filter to force the removal of index.cfm from the URL (i.e. http://www.site.com/index.cfm becomes http://www.site.com/). Well this is fine for most of the site except for a password protected area of the site (which does not need the rewrite, as this part of the site does not affect SEO).

From what I have read online I need to set up a rewrite condition which will ignore the rewrite statement which removes the index.cfm extension.

So just to be clear I want the rewrite to operate as normal on http://www.site.com/ but not when the user navigates here: http://www.site.com/workflow/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

EDIT: I tried the rule that Cade recommended, but it seems that index.cfm is still being removed when I try to navigate to the workflow sub directory.  For some reason having the index.cfm being removed is making it impossible to log into the workflow portal.  Any suggestions??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ISAPI Rewrite 3 Rule:  `RewriteRule ^workflow/(.*)$ /workflow/$1 [NC,L]`

ISAPI Rewrite 2 Rule:  `RewriteRule /workflow/(.*) /workflow/$1 [NC,L]`

This will pass any requests for workflow directly through to the workflow folder.  You would place this before your rewrite rule that removes index.cfm from the URL.

Comment: Sweet.  I will give it a try but that looks good.  I do not know what it is about regular expressions, but they majorly throw me off.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay on getting to this.  Unfortunately this did not work.  I have: RewriteRule ^workflow/(.*)$ /workflow/$1 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule (.*)/index.cfm$ $1/ [I,RP] and the index.cfm is still being removed when trying to navigate to site.com/workflow.  Any idea?

Comment: What ISAPI plugin are you using?  That will affect the syntax of the regex.

Comment: Try this rule for ISAPI Rewrite 2: RewriteRule /workflow/(.*) /workflow/$1 [NC,L]

Comment: I do, however, suggest upgrading to ISAPI Rewrite 3 as it more closely implements mod_rewrite from Apache. We use ISAPI rewrite 3 on all of our servers and it works well.